# Unable switch to HTTPS protocol in Local Port Forwarding in VS Code v1.85.0

Tags: visual-studio-code

Here is how to reproduce my issue:

1. Run & Debug my ASP.NET Core Web API. It listen HTTPS on Port 7045.
2. Forward a port: 7045
3. Switch Port Visibility to Public.
4. Change Port Protocol to HTTPS. But it never switch to HTTPS.

   [image]
5. I choose Preview in Editor. Nothing show up.

   [image]

Is there anything I can do?